# Why does cxf.xml not load when using WebClient in a JUnit test

Tags: java, rest, junit, cxf, webclient

I have an application that uses Spring and CXF REST web services and everything works happily there, but I'm writing JUnit tests for the REST web services and finding that the cxf.xml file is never loaded which is a problem as we use it for the authentication data.

The JUnit tests do not use Spring at all, they are just simple bean tests making calls to the client using some simple code as follows....

```
    public static <RQ, RS> RS callXMLService(RQ request, String host, String path, Class<RS> responseClass)
{
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(host);
    client.path(path);
    client.type("application/xml");
    client.accept("text/xml");

    RS response = client.post(request, responseClass);

    int status = client.getResponse().getStatus();
    if (status == 200)
    {
        return response;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I've set breakpoints within CXF itself at the points in BusinessApplicationContext and SpringBusFatory where the configuration should be loaded but they are never triggered.

If the service I need doesn't have authentication then it will work, but that's only because it hasn't needed anything from cxf.xml to run.

How do I get the CXF WebClient to load the cxf properties in a JUnit test?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've had the same problem, placed the cxf.xml file in the root of the classpath but it did not load and the required settings where never applied.

After I added spring-context as a dependency, I finally got it working. See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html

> Note starting with CXF 2.6.0, Maven users will need to add the following dependency for the cxf.xml file to be read:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>  (or most recent supported)
</dependency>
```